# How to change dynamically created array if array is empty JQplot?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, jqplot

I am trying to create a line chart that has a constant line and a dynamically generated line. At the moment when I do not pass any values into the array, jqplot will not draw anything for my dynamic line.

I would like jqplot to have a default value of 1 if the dynamic line is empty or has only say 1 out of 5 values, for example if the array generates [] it would like it to generate [[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]] and if the array generates [[4],[3],[],[],[]] I would like it to be able to put a 1 in the empty array e.g. [[4],[3],[1],[1],[1]]

any help on this would be really appreciated.

here is some of the code I have so far;

```
 var values = $('input:radio:checked').map(function () { 
return this.value
}).get(); 

var line1 =[[1,values[0],1], [2,values[1],1], [3,values[2],1], [4,values[3],1],[5,values[4],1]];
var line2 =[[1,4],[2,5],[3,4],[4,5],[5,5]];

 $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [line2,line1],
{
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check the length of the array before you set it and act accordingly? 
For this you could write your own method of retrieving the value, for example:

```
function getValue(index){
   return (values[index].length > 0 ? values[index] : [1];
}
```

As per the given code snippet in `line1` you could use it like this:

```
var line1 = [[1,getValue(0),1], [2,getValue(1),1], [3,getValue(2),1], [4,getValue(3),1],[5,getValue(4),1]];
```

*Please do consider I am not 100% sure what you are after, but this is my best guess :)*